# Общезначимость атрибута <kbd>

Tags: html, атрибуты

Скажите, пожалуйста, этот атрибут используется только на этом сайте или он применяется вообще в html?

---

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. А, это, получается, работает только в ответах.

Comment: Здравствуйте!))

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/html/kbd

Comment: Так там же в результате ничего серым прямоугольником с закругленными углами не выделено. <kbd> Shift </kbd>

Comment: Ну так через css стили сделайте и будет.

Comment: Я не пойму, а что здесь случилось? Ведь работало же: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

Comment: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. А, это, получается, работает только в ответах.

Comment: А не дадите один примерчик?

Comment: [Вот здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing), как будто то, что надо, только вот ширина фиксирована, а если применить это для кнопок, ширина нужна разная.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а при применении стиля CSS результат всегда отображается в отдельной строке?